# ATC Check - prio 3 message - "Text element missing in a character string"

Tags: abap

I am getting message  "Text element missing in a character string" during ATC Checks for constant.

```
CONSTANTS c_north TYPE c LENGTH 5 VALUE 'North'.
```

How can i remove  "Text element missing in a character string",

Please let me know what is the best solution.

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is issued, because of a hardcoded text, which cannot be translated. To simply remove the message you have to use a pragma, add `##NO_TEXT` before (!) the line closing dot:

```
CONSTANTS c_north TYPE c LENGTH 5 VALUE 'North' ##NO_TEXT.
```

This removes the message, however does not solve the original problem, that the hardcoded text cannot be translated (which can be an issue in a multi-language system landscape). To overcome this you can create a text element in the program and use the text element instead of the constant.

You can also use Extenden Program Check (Ctrl + F4 or just below ATC in the menu) as well, which in many cases gives more detailed information about weak points in the program and how to overcome these.